# Unalloacte space on RAID1 over LVM

Tags: raid, lvm

I ran into situation where i resized vg and pv under raid1 and also md0 itself, but gparted still se whole disk as locked, i cant use free space i made to build new RAID partition, not sure why. My current setting follows:

```
root@cdp1-ora:~# lsblk              
NAME                    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                       8:0    0 119.2G  0 disk  
|-sda1                    8:1    0     9M  0 part  
`-sda2                    8:2    0 119.2G  0 part  
  `-md0                   9:0    0    31G  0 raid1 
    `-vg.system-lv.root 253:0    0    30G  0 lvm   /
sdb                       8:16   0 119.2G  0 disk  
root@cdp1-ora:~# pvdisplay 
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/md0
  VG Name               vg.system
  PV Size               30.27 GiB / not usable 3.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes 
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              7749
  Free PE               69
  Allocated PE          7680
  PV UUID               97qFfS-qcNo-Wp8W-QfWj-Ilqx-e7Jw-uMLXX7

root@cdp1-ora:~# vgdisplay 
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               vg.system
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  33
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                1
  Open LV               1
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               30.27 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              7749
  Alloc PE / Size       7680 / 30.00 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       69 / 276.00 MiB
  VG UUID               TehY47-dnpp-ZjnM-kIWO-UwMG-dXxO-OVeT6N

root@cdp1-ora:~# lvdisplay 
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vg.system/lv.root
  LV Name                lv.root
  VG Name                vg.system
  LV UUID                xuvEmB-RPjj-hW3d-oFsn-pdHZ-xT58-QgIfQ2
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time debian, 2018-08-29 12:11:12 +0200
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                30.00 GiB
  Current LE             7680
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:0

root@cdp1-ora:~#
```

Id like to use remaining 80G to build RAID0 with sdb.

Comment: The lvm-settings are completly not part of your problem. Can you please post the *entire* output of `lsblk`? You cut off at sdb. Also which system do you use? Earlier versions of gparted refuse to resize mounted partitions.

Comment: sdb is as it is, its full output of lsblk, before it had root as well, since its experiment, i just made that ride1 forcefully 1disk - iam working with live system, cant reinstall it with proper partitioning so iam trying to crate SWAP over sda and sdb using free space and RAID0 - for better performance. Gparted is the latest version from website. I tried to size md0 to max size with mdadm and then tried to resize it in gparted, after apply, the free space i unalloacted simplly disapears and is still part of sda - no unallocated space to work with

Comment: So basically you have yourself a faulty RAID1. You don't have to reinstall it but you can use a live system and resize the volumes with that. See here: https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-resize-raid-partitions-shrink-and-grow-software-raid

Answer (score 0):

So my issue was that i was disassembling building before the roof.

After few days of struggling, on how to resize live server(meaning it could not been reinstalled from scratch,but rebooted no problem) with LVM under RAID1 i figured out the possibly correct path - my case was very specific but beacuse of that it required use of possibly all disk management techniques.

Use live CD

First remove lv.youwantremove

Then you resize VG. PV. to bit lower than anticipated size of resized raid

Then use fdisk to resize partiton, if its on live/mounted system, reboot

THEN grow md* to max size of your new partiton - this way, hes going to use all available space minus little bit of space for headers. Doing this by specifying whole space your self while --grow, hes just going to use all space for data and overgrow md0 since headers will not fit md0 - boot fails, raid looks corrupted,reporting hes using more space than avilable - i fixed this using live CD at this stage - there i used grow again which worked ask described above.

Now you can use fdisk to create new partition and later resemble raid as you wish, in my case it was RAID1 - lv.root + lv.cache spited to RAID1 - lv.root, RAID0 - lv.cache. System still works. 
There was no way to reinstall it and do this all from scratch avoiding all this.

This is not the original problem, i may post this to previous questions i had regarding my issue as i was progressing slowly forward, crashing often, asking even more often.